# Can you get the Bluetooth MAC Address of a Bluetooth Device when you have its name?

Tags: c++, winapi, bluetooth, mac-address

I'm currently creating a program in C++ that allows devices (currently just my smartphone) to be paired to the PC. I'm using the WinApi functions and it actually works rather well.

For the programm to work I currently need to pass the Bluetooth MAC Address of the device to the programm, more specifically, the **BluetoothRegisterForAuthenticationEx** MSDN function needs it to pair the device.

Now, I actually don't want to type in my Bluetooth MAC Address, but it would be fine to enter the Device Name (or something else) in order to pair the device.

I looked through the winapi bluetooth functions, but didn't find anything, so my question for you is,

Can I, programmatically, get the Bluetooth MAC Address of a certain device when I have other informations (for example the device name) without being already paired?
And if so, how?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the exact method I was searching for in the Windows SDK samples.

Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v7.0\Samples\netds\winsock\bluetooth

The mehtod is called `NameToBthAddr` and does pretty much what Eric Lemanissier was suggesting.

Answer (score 0):

You can start a device discovery using `WSALookupServiceBegin` and `WSALookupServiceNext`, then for each device detected (each `WSAQUERYSET`) compare the `lpszServiceInstanceName`with the name typed by the user. If it matches, then you have the mac address in the `lpcsaBuffer->RemoteAddr.lpSockaddr` field . This field can be cast to `PSOCKADDR_BTH`, then you get the MAC addr in `PSOCKADDR_BTH->btAddr`

```
WSAQUERYSET querySet;
memset(&querySet, 0, sizeof(querySet));
querySet.dwSize = sizeof(querySet);
querySet.dwNameSpace = NS_BTH;
HANDLE hLookup;
if(0 != WSALookupServiceBegin(&querySet, LUP_CONTAINERS | LUP_FLUSHCACHE, &hLookup))
{
    if(WSAGetLastError() != WSASERVICE_NOT_FOUND)
    {
        // error during WSALookupServiceBegin
    }
    else
    {
        //No BlueTooth device Found
    }
    return res;
}
DWORD deviceLength = 2000;
char buf[deviceLength];
WSAQUERYSET* pDevice = PWSAQUERYSET(buf);
while (0 == WSALookupServiceNext(hLookup, LUP_RETURN_ADDR | LUP_RETURN_NAME, &deviceLength, pDevice))
{
    PSOCKADDR_BTH sa = PSOCKADDR_BTH(pDevice->lpcsaBuffer->RemoteAddr.lpSockaddr);
    if(sa->addressFamily != AF_BTH)
    {
       // Address family is not AF_BTH  for bluetooth device discovered
        continue;
    }
    //the name is available in pDevice->lpszServiceInstanceName
    //the MAC address is available in sa->btAddr
}
WSALookupServiceEnd(hLookup);
```

Comment: First of all, thanks.
For the `WSALookupServiceBegin` function to work, I need a `lpServiceClassId`, a GUID that identifies the service I'm searching for. I looked into `SvcGuid.h` where the example I found got its GUID but nothing really seems to fit.

Do you know by chance which one I have to use to find Bluetooth devices/ services? Or did I get that one wrong?

Comment: You do not need a ServiceClassId if you perform a device detection, you need it only when you perform a service detection. I edited my answer with pseudo-code.